# Button Event not getting fired when put inside Tab Panel in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

I have put two buttons inside a tab Panel in Sencha Touch 2 application. The code is given below:

```
var btnAttendance = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Take Attendance',
    padding: 10,
    width: 200,
    handler: function () {
        alert('a');
    }
});

var btnAddUser = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Add User',
    padding: 10,
    width: 200,
    handler: function () {
        alert('a');
    }
});

var buttonContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Home',
    defaults: {
        margin: 5
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    padding: 10,
    items: [
        btnAttendance,
        btnAddUser
    ]
});

Ext.application({
    requires: [
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
    ],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items: [
                buttonContainer,
                {
                    title: 'Present',
                    items: {
                        html: '2',
                        centered: true
                    },
                    cls: 'present'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Absent',
                    items: {
                        html: '3',
                        centered: true
                    },
                    cls: 'absent'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried modifying the handler function as:

handler: function (button, event)

But this also doesn't work.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Here is the link to the fiddle: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/bcYJM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all your code inside `Ext.application...` and `launch:function(){...}...`. Your code is working fine. See [demonstration here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#H7Sto).

But then again, `buttonContainer` is not really being added to any tab panel. If you change the tab, you can see `buttonContainer` is gone once to change the tabs. If you want to add it inside any tab do this-

First -
Set `fullscreen:false` to you `buttonContainer` panel.

```
var buttonContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: false,
       ....... //rest of the code.
```

And suppose you want to add those buttons in `Present` tab. You can do this with following--

```
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Present',
                cls: 'present',
                items: [
                    {
                        html: '2',
                        centered: true
                    },

                        buttonContainer

                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Absent',
                items: {
                    html: '3',
                    centered: true
                },
                cls: 'absent'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Here, `buttonContainer` is added as an item inside `present` tab only. You can switch the tabs and can see buttons there with correct event handler.
See this [demo here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#r2V6B)

If you follow MVC architecture, your job becomes much easier writing application having multiple views and user interactions. ST is all about MVC and it's good practice to follow it.